# Hadoop Map/Reduce Mapper 'map' method and logs

Tags: java, hadoop, log4j, mapreduce, hdfs

I've recently been asked to look into speeding up a mapreduce project.
I'm trying to view log4j log information which is being generated within the 'map' method of a class which implements: `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper`

Within this class there are the following methods:

```
@Override
public void configure( .. ) { .. }

public static void doCompileAndAdd( .. ) { .. }

public void map( .. ) { .. }
```

Logging information is available for the configure method and the `doCompileAndAdd` method (which is called from the configure method); however, no log information is being displayed for the 'map' method.

I've also tried simply using `System.out.println( .. )` within the map method without success.

Is there anyone who might be able to help to shed some light on this issue?

Thanks, 
Telax

Answer (score 4):

Since the mapper classes actually run in tasks distributed across nodes in the cluster, the stdout from those tasks appears in the individual logs for each task.  The simplest way to see those logs is to go to the job tracker page for the cluster, usually at `http://namenode:50030/jobtracker.jsp`.  From there you can select the job and then select the map tasks you are interested in the logs for.

Comment: Hi HC, 

That's exactly where I've been looking through the logs. I've tried looking on each of the nodes which are running the mapper tasks but there's no sign of my 'map' method logging in there either. My colleges assure me that the 'map' method is called from within the hadoop library and so I must take them at their word on this, otherwise my assumption would be that the method isn't called at all.

Comment: Personally, I generally ssh into the data node directly to look at the task logs.  You should be able to find your stdout output in a file named something like this: `/var/log/hadoop/userlogs/job_201208221552_0015/attempt_201208221552_0015_m_000000_0/stdout`

Comment: Follow the [link](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/09/apache-hadoop-log-files-where-to-find-them-in-cdh-and-what-info-they-contain/) for clearness